# Industry Values for Beta (β) in BJT current amplification

Tags: transistors, bjt, gain, semiconductors

I recently completed a lab involving the use of BJT's and as part of my post-lab analysis I was curious at looking in to the max/min values of β in current amplification (Using formula would obviously yield infinite possibilities)

\$β = {I_{C} \over I_{B}} \$

I was having trouble finding a source on what values are common.

Comment: What kind of transistors were you using in your lab?

Comment: npn BJT model 2N3904

Comment: Just a note: people mentioned reading datasheets in their answers, which is right. But nobody mentioned that this parameter is usually labeled **hFE** in datasheets, not **β**.

Answer (score 3):

As a general answer to what values of B are common out of all the BJTs commonly available right now;  One quick way to find out what's common would be to search for what's in stock at the major distributors, (Mouser, Digikey, Avnet, Arrow, etc).

A search on Digikey for all currently stocked BJTs in active production gives 3723 unique manufacturer part numbers.  Given B for each of those part numbers we have the following statistics.

Minimum B = 3 (lowest value)
Maximum B = 1000 (highest value)
Average B = 559 (arithmetic mean)
Median B = 100 (center of the list)
Mode B = 100 (most common value)
90% of the B values fall within the range 25 to 750.
80% of the B value fall within the range 40 to 270.

I used the values of B in the Digikey database to generate the above statistics.  The values of B in the Digikey database usually match the typical value given in the table in the manufacturer datasheet for each transistor.  The value of B is usually given for a specific operating point that the manufacturer thought was relevant.

Generally B is different for each unit manufactured and can also change if the operating conditions change(temperature, collector current, collector emitter voltage, etc).  So my answer should only be taken as a rough estimate of what's out there.

Comment: I'm guessing some of your really high values are from darlingtons, not single transistors.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop Some were, but some like the DSC2A01T0L had B=1000 and didn't mention that they were Darlington in the datasheet, but that could just be lack of detail.

Answer (score 3):

As @dim pointed out, \$\beta\$ is the same as hFE, and it will be listed as the latter on a datasheet at a few currents and at some substantial Vce.

Here is an example from the Fairchild data sheet:

[image]

So at 10mA and 1V Vce and 25 degrees C the DC current gain will measure between 100 and 300, guaranteed. If you hold it in your fingers during the measurement it will increase from the heating!

To see how it varies with temperature and current, typically, you can refer to the graph:

[image]

(Pulsed gain is specified because they want to neglect the effects of self-heating)

You can use the guaranteed numbers and extrapolate what the effects of temperature will be or interpolate for different currents.

If you are using the transistor as a simple switch you may not care about hFE (directly) at all, only the current required to saturate the transistor, which will be much higher than hFE for a Vce of 1V would predict. You may care about the maximum gain if there can be a bit of base current but usually you can say that if Vbe is less than (say 300mV) that the collector current resulting will be negligible over a normal temperature range (that voltage will be less if you have to operate at very high temperatures because hFE increases and the Vbe for a given base current decreases- a double whammy). If you are just driving a base with a CMOS gate or MCU the voltage is usually < 100mV and the resulting current can be ignored. It also helps that hFE is typically drops at very low currents so battery drain etc is not impacted as badly as you might expect.

Transistors aimed at analog applications often have hFE bins that at are relatively narrow (typically about a 2:1 range) - for example an SS8050C has hFE between 120 and 200 under specific conditions. Often used in cost-sensitive applications.

You'll want to pay particular attention to the hFE changes with temperature if you want to do low distortion amplifiers because the hFE changes with temperature can cause large thermal 'tails' on the open-loop response.

It's best to design so that your circuit will work over all possible variations of hFE (with your specified part) without any manual adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

### Check the datasheet, but don't expect any particular value from any given transistor either!

The answer to this question is RTFDS -- Read The Friendly DataSheet.  Most transistor datasheets will provide minimum betas for selected operating points, as well as a typical or maximum beta value for one or two of them.  Some datasheets may also provide a curve of typical beta vs collector current, but this isn't guaranteed.

For your transistor, the ubiquitous 2N3904, [Fairchild's datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/2N/2N3904.pdf) quotes a minimum beta of 100 and a typical of 300 at 10mA collector current and 1V from collector to emitter.  So, I'd use a beta of 100 for calculations for the forward-active region, while designing the circuit to be as beta-independent as possible -- transistor beta is *not* a tightly controlled parameter!

Answer (score 1):

To get value of gain for a transistor, look in something called its *datasheet*.  These will usually specify the minimum gain at a few operating points.  Sometimes they also give typical values, but there is little useful you can do with these.

The upper bound on gain is rarely specified, and can be 10x or more the minimum.  Good circuits work with the transistor gain from the minimum guaranteed to infinite.  That's actually not as hard to design to as it may sound.